# How to know which button is selected in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create 3 buttons. When I press on one button, I want that to be expand it with the x button. But instead of that, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong ? I will paste the code below.

This is the reutilizabile button I've created.

```
struct RCHChipView: View {
    var rchChip: RCHChip
    var action: () -> Void

    init(
        rchChip: RCHChip,
         action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.rchChip = rchChip
        self.action = action
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                action()
            } label: {
                Text(rchChip.title)
            }
            if rchChip.isSelected {
                Button {
                    rchChip.isSelected = false
                } label: {
                        Image("NavigationCloseIcon")
                            .resizable()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RCHChip: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, title: String, isSelected: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self._isSelected = isSelected
    }
}
```

Here, I will show you how I'm trying to display the buttons.

```
 @State private var rchChip: [RCHChip] = [RCHChip(title: "Datum"), RCHChip(title: "Person")]
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(rchChip) { chip in
                                RCHChipView(rchChip: rchChip.first(where: {$0.id == chip.id}) ?? RCHChip(id: "", title: "", isSelected: .constant(false))) {
                                    chip.isSelected = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite strange and I didn't really understand all of it but here is a solution that seems to work

First of all, you cannot use `@Binding` outside a View so I changed the struct to

```
struct RCHChip: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, title: String, isSelected: Bool = false) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}
```

In the `RCHChipView` I found the definition of `action` strange since it didn't take any input nor returned anything. I changed it to the have the following signature

```
var action: (RCHChip) -> RCHChip
```

and to be able to modify a view property from outside of the view it needs to be a `@Bindning` so I changed `rchChip` to

```
@Binding var rchChip: RCHChip
```

the execution of the action property was then changed to

```
Button {
    self.rchChip = action(rchChip)
}
```

And for the calling view I used the following code

```
@State private var rchChips: [RCHChip] = [RCHChip(title: "Datum"), RCHChip(title: "Person")]

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach($rchChips) { chip in
            RCHChipView(rchChip: chip, action: { chip in
                var copy = chip
                copy.isSelected = true
                return copy
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure this can be improved upon but it should be a step forward compared to your current solution and it does compile and run :)

Comment: Thank you very much, It is working:)
Is there a way to select only one button ?
Because if I have 2 buttons I can select them both

Comment: Select? Do you mean enable/disable buttons?

Comment: No, I mean, for now, I can select both buttons, if my array of RCHChip contains 2 element, for example. I only want to select 1 at a time

Comment: You mean only one button should be visible, if so you could filter the rchChips array perhaps by using a computed property

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to do with the behaviour of `Binding` variables.

Try:

```
struct RCHChipView: View {
    var rchChip: RCHChip
    var action: () -> Void

    init(
        rchChip: RCHChip,
         action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.rchChip = rchChip
        self.action = action
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                action()
            } label: {
                Text(rchChip.title)
            }
            if rchChip.isSelected {
                Button {
                    rchChip.isSelected.wrappedValue = false
                } label: {
                        Image("NavigationCloseIcon")
                            .resizable()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference being using the `.wrappedValue` for the `Binding` variable. Here's a slight change to the `ForEach`:

```
ForEach($rchChip) { $chip in
    RCHChipView(
        rchChip: chip,
        action: { $chip.wrappedValue.isSelected = true }
    )
}
```

`$` is how you refer to `Binding` variables.

Comment: Hi, your solution is not working :)